# Swap R and B color channel values in a directory of images? Python

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

I've got a big directory of screenshots.   Silly me I didn't check that they were coming out fine and found out the hard way VLC has a bug with FRAPS True RGB.  Luckily it seems fixable, it looks like the only problem is that the R and B channels were swapped.

Using python's PIL I'd like to grab the red and blue values for each pixel for each image and then reinsert them swapped.

I know how to walk through a directory so the main piece I'm missing is the best way to swap the values.  I think I could do it pixel for pixel but maybe there's a more pythonic way, perhaps batching it all in one command?

Any example code or links would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
from PIL import Image


dirPath = r"D:\Fraps\Movies\Screens"
dirList = os.listdir(dirPath)
outPath = r"D:\Fraps\Movies\Screens\Output"

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(dirPath):
   for filename in files:
       if filename.endswith('.png'):
            print("Opening:"+filename)
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
            im = Image.open(thefile)
            #im.load()

            width, height = im.size

            im_rgb = im.convert('RGB')

            for x in range(0, width):
                for y in range(0,height):
                    r, g, b = im_rgb.getpixel((x, y))
                    im_rgb.putpixel((x, y), (b, g, r))

            print("Saving:"+filename)
            #outfile, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
            outfile = os.path.join(outPath,filename)
            im_rgb.save(outfile, "PNG")


print("Ding!")
```

Answer (score 6):

Building on @veta's answer, the process may be greatly accelerated by working on color channels instead of individual pixels:

In the loop for each file, channels may be swapped like this:

```
r, g, b = im_rgb.split()
im_rgb = Image.merge('RGB', (b, g, r))
```

Just use these two lines instead of the nested loops in veta's answer. This should run considerably faster.

This solution first uses `Image.split()` to create three separate images, one for each R, G, B, channel. Then `Image.merge()` is used to create a new RGB image with swapped R and B channels.

Answer (score 2):

You can let ImageMagick do that for you. Let's make a red-black gradient image like this:

```
convert -size 256x100 gradient:red-black in.png
```

[image]

Now we can load it up, separate the R, G and B channels, swap the Red with the Blue and recombine them into the output image:

```
convert in.png -separate -swap 0,2 -combine out.png
```

[image]

ImageMagick is installed on most Linux distros and available for OSX (ideally via `homebrew`) and also for Windows from [here](http://imagemagick.org).

If you want to do a whole directory of `PNG` files, for example, you would do

```
find . -iname "*.png" -exec convert "{}" -separate -swap 0,2 -combine {} \;
```

if you are on Linux or OS X.

If you are on Windows, you would need to do something like this with the mad Windows syntax:

```
FOR %%F in (*.PNG) DO convert "%%F" -separate -swap 0,2 -combine "%%F
```

Comment: oh that's slick, I ended up getting python to do it but I'd like to know more about this.  How would I use this for an entire directory, for example?  Can I use a directory as the infile and add a -r flag?

Comment: Please have another look - I have updated my answer.

Comment: Note as well there are Python bindings for ImageMagick, see: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php

Comment: Hi @AdamParkin, Thanks for pointing that out - it was rather remiss of me not to have mentioned the Python bindings.